# Gauss elimination, reordering rows based on pivot values

Tags: function-construction, linear-algebra

I'm trying to create a code for Gauss elimination such that if there's a zero pivot during elimination, the equation will be reordered with the next row with a non-zero element and if it can't do that then produce a warning. I already have the code for detecting the zero pivot, I'm just not sure how to create the rest.

This is the code:

```
GaussElimination[A_, b_] := (
  n = Length[A];
  G = Transpose[Insert[Transpose[A], b, n + 1]];
  Flag = 0;
  For[k = 1, k <= n, k++, If[G[[k, k]] == 0,
    Flag = 1,
    (Do[
      G[[i]] = G[[i]] - G[[i, k]]/G[[k, k]]*G[[k]],
      {i, k + 1, n}])]];
  If[Flag == 1,
   "zero pivot detected during elimination.", 
   x = Table[0, {i, 1, n}];
   For[i = n, i >= 1, i = i - 1,
    x[[i]] =
     (G[[i, n + 1]] - Sum[G[[i, l]]*x[[l]], {l, i + 1, n}])/G[[i, i]]];
   x])
```

Comment: What is the goal? To put all rows with only zeros at the bottom of the matrix?

Comment: The goal is to do gauss elimination but when it comes across a zero pivot it uses the next row with a non-zero element and continue with gauss elimination